# Cors issue between rest api application server(express) and Angulars js application while running on different ports

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

Our app is built on decoupled MEAN stack architecture. I am trying to make successful request from my Angular front end to our backend. The backend definitely returns JSON. But every time I make a request from the frontend to the backend I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/recipes/175169. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have the following setup on the backend to accept cross origin requests:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

  next();
});
```

The request being made from the frontend is:

```
recipe.controller('RecipeController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.loadRecipe = function() {
    $http({
      url: 'http://localhost:9000/recipes/175169',
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data)
    })
}
```

If I run the following to disable chrome, the request will work, but that doesn't seem like a real solution so much as a jenky work around.

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app--args --disable-web-security
```

This is my first StackOverflow post, and I am relatively new to Express and the MEAN stack, so I apologize if the solution is obvious. I have done quite a bit of research, and none of the solutions, I've found have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, try and change the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' header to:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Second, if its only for development purposes, I recommend using [Chrome CORS Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. The plugin works well. The changed header doesn't seem to have any effect.